# Android: Store a destination activity in a bundle

Tags: android, class, android-intent, bundle

So I'm working on this project, and its rather large in size. I've have put a kind of 'behind the scenes' security login system in.

Pretty much, all the activities extend the `subActivity` class, and the `subActivity` extents `Activity`. This has allowed me to make every form automatically `.putExtra()` when it starts a new activity, and on every `onCreate()` it will check the incoming data and determine whether it should force the user to login (push them to the `LoginActivity`).

So right now, the login activity, on successful login, it loads to the `MainActivity`. I want it to dynamically load the activity the user was last at...

This means, store the class of the activity that launched the `LoginActivity` in the extras, and then have the `LoginActivity`, on successful login, get the class from the extras and use it to start the `Activity`.

I'm looking for the simplest way possible, I was trying serializable, but was having a lot of issues and thought there must be another way to just pass a reference to the 'destination' class.

Hope this makes sense!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Java reflection API:

Call your login activity like this:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("activity", getClass().getName());
startActivity(intent);
```

Then parse the calling activity's name in login activity and go back to it after successful log in:

```java
private String mActivity;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    // ...

    mActivity = "";
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
        mActivity = extras.getString("activity");
    }
}

@Override public void onClick(View view)
{
    try {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(mActivity);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, cls));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need!!! I implemented it, but the try catch is always failing. I Log'd the Class cls references, (using toString())... and it prints out class ca.rgod.smartmed.UserInfo .. thats the right class, but it fails when it tries to start that activity? :S

Comment: Got it working, my mistake! Cheers this did exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

In the `LoginActivity`, simply call `finish()` which will return to the next `Activity` on the Stack, in your case going back to the previous one.

Comment: The problem with this approach, is that each activity is expecting a piece of data from the Extras to validate it coming from another form, and not the homescreen...

Answer (score 0):

You can start your login activity by startActivityForResult and then check result of login activity in your main activity. Look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Comment: So I check it in the MainActivity onResult, but I don't see how this helps me pass a reference to what class I need to direct to.

Comment: What for? After login activity is finished, activity that called login activity would become active. And with result of login.

Comment: I finish() the launching activity to avoid the ability to bypass the login screen.

Comment: How can you bypass login activity if it running on creating of main activity? Finish launching activity if login activity return something that not equals OK.